# How to properly implement scrollHeight or scrollTop for div messages using Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement chat messages in Reactjs. The chat messages gets appended properly and it's working fine.

Here is my issue: the chat message when it gets to the bottom does not scroll up.

I am looking at implementing something like chat div auto scrollup when message gets to bottom.

```
scrollToBottom() {
  chat_messages.scrollTop = chat_messages.scrollHeight;
}
```

Is there any workaround for this?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

<style>

.chat_container{

background:blue;
height:40%;
max-height:40%;

width: 60%;
max-width: 60%;
 overflow-y: auto;

}


.chat_message{

background:green;
color:white;
padding:10px;
border:none;

}

.myFooter{
bottom:0px;
position:fixed;
background:red;
height:10%;
max-height:10%;

width: 60%;
max-width: 60%;


}
</style>
   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">


class Application extends React.Component {

//function Application() {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

const sender = 'John';

    this.state = {
message: '',
value: '',
sname: sender,
date: new Date(),
messages: []
};

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }

handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({message: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
   // alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.message);
    event.preventDefault();

const data = {'message': this.state.message}
 this.setState({
            messages : this.state.messages.concat([data])
        });
//$(".chat_container").animate({ scrollTop: 20000000 }, "slow");
 this.scrollToBottom();

  }



scrollToBottom() {
  chat_messages.scrollTop = chat_messages.scrollHeight;
}

componentDidMount() {
// fetch content axio or ajax
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="chat_container">


  <h2>Welcome to Chat: Time is: {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>

      

 {this.state.messages.map((m, e) => (


              <div key={e}>


               
<div className="chat_message">chat: {m.message} ---{this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}</div> 

              </div>
            ))}

       
        </div>

<div className="myFooter">
 <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.message} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
</div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got your example to work with:

```
bottomRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
```

Here's the full code; I took the honor of converting it to a functional React component and used the useRef hook (the scroll happens anytime the messages state is updated):

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App(props) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const currentDate = new Date();
  const bottomRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch content axio or ajax
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    bottomRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [messages]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    // alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.message);
    event.preventDefault();
    const newMessages = messages;
    const data = { message: message, date: new Date() };
    setMessages(newMessages.concat([data]));
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h2>Welcome to Chat: Time is: {currentDate.toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>

      <div className="chat_container">
        {messages.map((m, e) => (
          <div key={e}>
            <div className="chat_message">
              chat: {m.message} ---{m.date.toLocaleTimeString()}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}

        <div id="bottom-reference" ref={bottomRef} />
      </div>

      <div className="myFooter">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" value={message} onChange={handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I used these styles to test the scrolling:

```
.chat_container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. All my codes are already in Class approach. I will mimick your functional approach and see how it goes. between thanks for your efforts